# Speech recognition with dates

Tags: android, date, nlp, speech-recognition, google-glass

I'm implementing a kind a calendar for Google Glass. In this calendar, I would like to be able to use speech recognition in order to select a calendar slot. For example it should be nice to say "first week of August" and android should be able to recognize the date.
I'm sure I have already saw that on Android but I cannot find it anymore.
Could you help me ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: The Wit.AI API can do that (check the `wit/datetime` entity) https://wit.ai

Comment: Thank you ! It's very interesting, I think I will be able to solve my problems with it !

Answer (score 1):

As Blacksad commented, Wit.AI API is a very good solution. It performs some nice natural language processing.
I recommend you not to use the .jar but directly the code inside. 
Here is an example of Glass Speech recognition combined with Wit.API

MainActivity :

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    displaySpeechRecognizer();
}

private static final int SPEECH_REQUEST = 0;

private void displaySpeechRecognizer() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        List<String> results = data
                .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String spokenText = results.get(0);
        Card c=new Card(getApplicationContext());
        c.setText("requesting wit api...");
        setContentView(c.getView());
        process(spokenText);

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void process(String text) {
    ConnexionTask c = new ConnexionTask() {
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                WitResponse response = null;
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                response = (WitResponse) gson.fromJson(result,
                        WitResponse.class);
                //process the response here
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    };
    c.execute(new String[] { text });
}
```

And here id the AsyncTask ConnexionTask :

```
public class connexion extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String _accessToken = "YOUR TOKEN HERE";

    protected String doInBackground(String... text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String response = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Requesting ...." + text[0]);
            String getUrl = String.format(
                    "%s%s",
                    new Object[] { "https://api.wit.ai/message?q=",
                            URLEncoder.encode(text[0], "utf-8") });
            System.out.println(getUrl);
            URL url = new URL(getUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format(
                    "Bearer %s", new Object[] { this._accessToken }));
            try {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                        urlConnection.getInputStream());
                response = IOUtils.toString(in);
                in.close();
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out
                    .println("An error occurred during the request, did you set your token correctly?");
        }
        return response;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }

}
```

I hope it will help you !